# Delete object from Django sqlite3 database, reducing the database size

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I have a table with many entries. I can very easily "delete" those entries, such that they no longer appear when using the Django Admin page. However, these records are still in the .sqlite3 file. I would like to reduce the .sqlite3 file size as a result of my deletion.

Google searches are so far fruitless on the topic.

** edit **

This should not be marked as a duplicate. While the question has been asked in other forms before, none of them are specifically tailored to using sqlite3 through a Django instance.

Comment: How do you delete those entries? If you end up deleting them through the `.delete()` method, they should not be on the DB file anymore.

Comment: They are still there . I've used .delete() from the Shell, and deleted via the admin interface

Comment: After deleting the instances running `sqlite3 /path/to/foo.db 'VACUUM;' ` will reduce the size

Answer (score 1):

The following method works for me...

```
python3 manage.py shell
>>> from OpenBench.models import Result
>>> r = Result.objects.filter()
>>> r._raw_delete(r.db)
>>>
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("vacuum;")
>>> quit()
```

This deletes all Result entries, and also reduces the size of the database file.

Comment: Didn't work for me for multiple reasons.  Typos, foreign key constraint errors.  Finally vacuum doesn't work, cursor is for wrong database type.

Comment: `cursor.exectute` should be `cursor.execute`